# Generic Types and HTTP Outbound Gateway Results

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-integration

So, I have an http outbound gateway that is invoking a given RESTful endpoint that returns a JSON array.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="shipments"
    http-method="GET"
    expected-response-type="java.util.List"
    url="http://codeserver.net/shipments?order={orderId}">

  <int-http:uri-variable name="orderId" expression="payload.
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

As you can see I specify a raw type for the type of the expected result. The underlying GSON converter (Jackson does the same) ends up returning a List of Maps. What I want to figure out is whether there's a way to specify the nature of the generic type in the collection.

I have not been able to figure out how to specify the `ParameterizedTypeReference` that the underlying `RestTemplate` can use so that the list object returned be of type `List<Shipment>` and not as it now that it maps it to a `List<Map<String,Object>>`.

It seems there's no way to deal with generics here.

Interestingly the `json-to-object-transformer` seems to suffer from the same problem.

Does anyone know how can I deal with generic types when doing this type of integration with HTTP gateways or will I have to resort to writing my own transformer for something so basic?

Comment: It looks like the Jira for Spring Integration contains some information on how to do this. It looks ugly though. I wonder if there is a better way to do this: [HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler loses generics as it executes the expectedResponseTypeExpression](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3052?jql=text%20~%20%22Generic%20Type%20and%20expected-response-type%22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pointed out to the correct JIRA ticket. From our tests it looks like:

```
expected-response-type-expression="T (org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandlerTests).testParameterizedTypeReference()"
```

Where it references to this method:

```
public static ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> testParameterizedTypeReference() {
     return new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};
}
```

Of course it can any `static` field with `ParameterizedTypeReference` type.

From other side you can populate desired value of `ParameterizedTypeReference` to the headers before and use it as:

```
expected-response-type-expression="headers.expectedResponseType"
```

You can even have some `bean` which may return appropriate type from some its method according to the `requestMessage`.

`JsonToObjectTransformer` can do something similar, but the result depends on the JSON engine. There is `JsonHeaders`, with which `JsonToObjectTransformer` gets deal when there is no provided `target-class` value.

**UPDATE**

As you noticed we are restricted with XML definition, when we can't specify a generic type and even can't privde an inline implementation from SpEL:

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Shipment>>() {}
```

doesn't work in SpEL at all.

I see the workaround for the XML definition with inline Script, for example Groovy:

```
<int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="expectedResponseType">
            <int-groovy:script>
                <![CDATA[
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<com.my.proj.domain.Shipment>>() {}
                ]]>
            </int-groovy:script>        
        </int:header>
</int:header-enricher>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It looks like it is really cumbersome to define the type though. For instance I cannot use `@GatewayHeader` because the `ParameterizedTypeReference` instance is not considered a [Java constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) and I cannot find a way to define the type token bean directly in XML, which even if possible would look ugly since in XML I'd have to escape `<` and `>`. Having to define a method or field that exposes the type is not very nice, but at least there is a way.

Comment: The Groovy trick is awesome! I wish I could upvote you again. I really did not want to define this outside the XML. Hopefully in the future there will be simpler ways to do this, but for the time being, this'll do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but with Java based configuration. I solved it using

```
org.springframework.integration.expression.ValueExpression
```

Here is part of my config

```
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> reference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};
    httpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.setExpectedResponseTypeExpression(new ValueExpression(reference));
```